# How to find the indirect nodes connected to a particular node in Spark Graphx

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I want to find the indirect nodes that are connected to a particular node.
I tried using the connected components class of Graph like below...

```
graph.connectedComponents
```

However, it is giving for all the graph..but i want for a particular node.

I have tried doing like below also.

```
graph.edges.filter(_.srcId == x).map(_.dstId)
```

This gives the direct nodes of a particular node and i have to recursive this by using RDD operations only.
Could any one please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
graph.edges.filter(_.srcId == x).map(e => (e.dstId, null)).join(
  graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either)
).flatMap{t => t._2._2}.collect.toSet
```

If you want to go deeper than this, I would use something like the **[Pregel API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pregel-api)**. Essentially, it lets you repeatedly send messages from node to node and aggregate the results.

**Edit: Pregel Solution**

I finally got the the iterations to stop on their own. **Edits** below. Given this graph:

```
graph.vertices.collect
res46: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Array[Long])] = Array((4,Array()), (8,Array()), (1,Array()), (9,Array()), (5,Array()), (6,Array()), (2,Array()), (3,Array()), (7,Array()))    

graph.edges.collect
res47: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Double]] = Array(Edge(1,2,0.0), Edge(2,3,0.0), Edge(3,4,0.0), Edge(5,6,0.0), Edge(6,7,0.0), Edge(7,8,0.0), Edge(8,9,0.0), Edge(4,2,0.0), Edge(6,9,0.0), Edge(7,9,0.0))
```

We are going to send messages of the type `Array[Long]` -- an array of all the `VertexIds` of connected nodes. Messages are going to go upstream -- the `dst` will send the `src` its `VertexId` along with all of the other downstream `VertexIds`. If the upstream node already knows about the connection, no message will be sent. Eventually, every node knows about every connected node and no more messages will be sent.

First we define our `vprog`. According to the docs:

> the user-defined vertex program which runs on each vertex and receives
>   the inbound message and computes a new vertex value. On the first
>   iteration the vertex program is invoked on all vertices and is passed
>   the default message. On subsequent iterations the vertex program is
>   only invoked on those vertices that receive messages.

```
def vprog(id: VertexId, orig: Array[Long], newly: Array[Long]) : Array[Long] = {
  (orig ++ newly).toSet.toArray
}
```

Then we define our `sendMsg` -- **edited:** swapped `src` & `dst`

> a user supplied function that is applied to out edges of vertices that
>   received messages in the current iteration

```
def sendMsg(trip: EdgeTriplet[Array[Long],Double]) : Iterator[(VertexId, Array[Long])] = {
  if (trip.srcAttr.intersect(trip.dstAttr ++ Array(trip.dstId)).length != (trip.dstAttr ++ Array(trip.dstId)).toSet.size) {
    Iterator((trip.srcId, (Array(trip.dstId) ++ trip.dstAttr).toSet.toArray ))
  } else Iterator.empty }
```

Next our `mergeMsg`:

> a user supplied function that takes two incoming messages of type A
>   and merges them into a single message of type A. This function must be
>   commutative and associative and ideally the size of A should not
>   increase.

Unfortunately, we're going to break the rule in the last sentence above:

```
def mergeMsg(a: Array[Long], b: Array[Long]) : Array[Long] = {
  (a ++ b).toSet.toArray
}
```

Then we run `pregel` -- **edited:** removed `maxIterations`, defaults to `Int.MaxValue`

```
val result = graph.pregel(Array[Long]())(vprog, sendMsg, mergeMsg)
```

And you can look at the results:

```
result.vertices.collect
res48: Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, Array[Long])] = Array((4,Array(4, 2, 3)), (8,Array(8, 9)), (1,Array(1, 2, 3, 4)), (9,Array(9)), (5,Array(5, 6, 9, 7, 8)), (6,Array(6, 7, 9, 8)), (2,Array(2, 3, 4)), (3,Array(3, 4, 2)), (7,Array(7, 8, 9)))
```

Comment: Well. That is not a simple problem at all, for sure. There's an `aggregateMessages` API you should take a look at, and an algorithm called `Pregel` you could use. Essentially, it lets you repeatedly send messages from node to node and aggregate the results. It is difficult to explain in a comment -- but imagine that in the first iteration of the algorithm, Node 7 would send (8,9) to Node 2 and Node 8 would send (10,11) to node 7. Then in the second iteration, node 7 would send (10,11) to node 2. So two iterations of Pregel you have your answer.

Comment: Sure David..i will work with that...and will update you ...Thanks

Comment: @DavidGriffin I've a similar problem: - **vertices** Array[(org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId, org.apache.spark.sql.Row)] - **edges** Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]] . In Row (vertices) there is also an array of hashtags. I'd count indirect and direct nodes in the path from a node with a specific hashtag and I don't know path length.

Comment: HI David...I am getting null pointer exception when using the above code in the cluster for other data...could you please help me how to get rid off the null pointer exception....in the Pregel...when using below line...                                      val result = graph.pregel(Array[Long]())(vprog, sendMsg, mergeMsg)

Comment: How are you defining the other data? Are you generating it programmatically? If so, post the code?